How to integrate a custom language with a Python-based blockchain for smart contracts?
I’ve built a simple blockchain using Python and created my own programming language, which is interpreted using Python. I’m now working on integrating my language to write smart contracts on the blockchain.
I have a few questions:

Should I pass the blockchain context to the interpreter so that smart contracts can access blockchain data? How should I structure this?
How should I handle payables (like in Solidity)? What’s the best way to manage funds and ensure secure transactions in smart contracts?
Are there any recommended practices or patterns for implementing smart contracts in a custom blockchain?

Any insights or examples would be really helpful!
